# Matlab fmincon: two-columned x-vector in linear inequality constraints

Tags: matlab, constraints, minimization

I'm trying to create a program which minimizes a function which has a two-columend vector *xy* with *i* rows as a variable.
The size of *i* depends on an excel-table I'm importing.

According to the Matlab-documentation for fmincon the linear inequality constraints have to have the form *A*x <= b*.
For each row of the xy-matrix I have 4 inequalities.

```
    x_i <= 0.5*w_T + 0.5*w_i
    y_i <= 0.5*h_T + 0.5*h_i
    -x_i <= 0.5*w_T - 0.5*w_i
    -y_i <= 0.5*h_T - 0.5*h_i
```

*h_T* and *w_T* are constants, *w_i* and *h_i* came from vectors with the dimension *i x 1*.

I have no idea how A and b have to look like. Is it even possible to have an 2D variable in fmincon? How do I let the solver know which constraints he has to use for which row of xy? (I believe there will be a similiar problem for the nonlinear inequality constrains)

Comment: `A` is a matrix and `x` and `b` are column vectors, such that the matrix product `Ax` is less than or equal to `b` (element-wise). For a matrix/vector product like this, the nth element of `b` is equal to the sum of the products of each element in the nth row of A with each element in `x`. Read up on [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) for more. In short, yes you can constrain as many variables as you want, your `A` and `b` will have `n` columns and rows respectively for `n` constraints.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't my problem that x (which should in my case be my _xy_) isn't a column vector but a matrix with the dimension _i x 2_?

Comment: You just have twice as many conditions, make it `2*i x 1`. This is the sort of problem when a lot of up-front pen and paper maths will save you coding headaches.

Comment: Yes, I already have an chaotic stack of paper in front of me. I already thought about doing this (so that I have an x vector {x_1,y_1,...,x_i,y_i}) . But here comes the second part of my initial question: how does Matlab know which element of my x-vector correlates with an element of my xy-matrix?

Comment: And if I'm solve this problem by using a vector with the form '[x_1,y_1,...,x_i,y_i]' I get for each "pair" of x and y an own 'A*x <= b sys'. How can I pass fmincon all i systems at the same time?